# Display associated Object Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to display subcategories with the Category they belong to. When creating a subcategory I use this to select the category.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :category, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.select :category, Category.all.collect {|c| [ c.title, c.id ] } %>
    </div>
    <%= error_span(@subcategory[:category]) %>
  </div>
```

If i validate the presence it is already emtpy so I think sth is maybe wrong here.

Now in the view I want to display the correct Category that the Subcategory belongs to.

This is what I tried

```
<td><%= Category.find(subcategory.category_id) %></td>
```

Unfortunately I just get the error **"Couldn't find Category without an ID"**

Comment: Please post the whole form and whatever controller action leads to this view

Comment: I just found the error. I forgot to add strong parameters in subcategory controller.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that i forgot to add strong parameters in the subcategory controller. That is why the id was not present in the view after creating the subcategory.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, we recently created a `Category` system using the [`ancestry` gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry).

I'd *highly* recommend it, as you will get to keep *all* your categories in a single model *and* you'll be able to display the categories & nested categories very simply:

--

**Ancestry Categories**

[image]

[image]

--

**Model**

The way this works is very simple - you just need a central `Category` model, which will have the `ancestry` gem attached:

```
#Ancestry
has_ancestry cache_depth: true
```

This will give you the ability to create a single `Category`, and then associate as many "ancestors" to it as you want. The beauty of this is that it will allow you to call a single `Category` object, and [utilize the many `Ancestry` methods for it](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry#navigating-your-tree):

[image]

The reason why this is important is because it will then allow you to create truly dynamic & nested `Categories` with a single model / table. And further, will give you the ability to create a view system which gives you the ability to call a partial like this:

```
#app/views/categories/index.html.erb
<%= render "category", collection: @categories, as: "category" %>

#app/views/categories/_category.html.erb
<%= link_to category.title, edit_admin_category_path(category) %>

<% if category.has_children? %>
    <%= render partial: "category", collection: category.children, as: "category" %>
<% end %>
```

- Please note I have changed this from my original code - this may create infinite recursions. If you find a "Stack Level Too Deep" error, I'll put the original code up

---

**Views**

Finally, you really shouldn't be calling your `Models` directly in your views. You need to ensure you've read up on the [MVC programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (which Rails is built on), which basically indicates that all your data objects need to be built & populated inside your controller actions, *not your views*

Comment: Thanks alot for the response. I just changed everything into the controller. Still getting used to all the MVC :) I will check also check out the gem .